# AJAX is supposed to return an object last added location name and id from sql database but it fails to do so, and returns an empty object

Tags: php

I've been on this for a week now, and cannot figure out why I get an empty object back from server-side. The code is accepting the location name from the input field of the modal. The XHR request header formed correctly and sent to the server while I was debbuging the function the input appeared as supposed, but I get result - an empty object. I wondering may by PHP file should be modified to return last added record to SQL database?
Thanks.

There is a piece of Javascript code :

```js
function insertLocation(e) {
    return new Promise((t, o) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "./libs/php/insertLocation.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                name: e
            },
            success: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                t(`${e.data.newRow[0].name} has been added!`);
            },
            error: function (e, t, o) {
                alert("insertLocation - The following error occured: " + e.status + " " + t);
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And PHP file which resolves the ajax:

```php
<?php
    // remove next two lines for production
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);
    
    // this includes the login details
    include("config.php");
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $conn = new mysqli($cd_host, $cd_user, $cd_password, $cd_dbname, $cd_port, $cd_socket);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        
        $output['status']['code'] = "300";
        $output['status']['name'] = "failure";
        $output['status']['description'] = "database unavailable";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
        $output['data'] = [];

        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit;
    }   
    
    $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO location(name) VALUES(?)');
    $query->bind_param("s", $_POST['name']);
    $query->execute();
    
    if (false === $query) 
    {
        $output['status']['code'] = "400";
        $output['status']['name'] = "executed";
        $output['status']['description'] = "query failed";  
        $output['data'] = [];

        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($output); 
        exit;
    }

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = [];
    
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

The following links contain application test images:

- [AJAX Sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duEVh.png)
- [Result Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wcJ.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are expecting, you are setting `$output['data']` to an empty array no matter what. You are never even doing any type of SELECT query.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a pure PHP problem? Please check your browser's network console for this

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton
I'm a novice in web development and trying to finish my study. This is a second project and I am not confident whether I'm writing the correct code.  Here is what have tried today: `code` $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
 $queryTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT id , name FROM location WHERE id= ?');
 $queryTest->bind_param("isi", $_REQUEST[$last_id], $_REQUEST['name'], 
        $_REQUEST[$last_id] );    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $output['data'] = $row; `code` But it didn't work either.

Comment: @NicoHaase This pure PHP problem, and as commented above there is incomplete PHP code in my project. At least now I'm sure I'm digging in the right direction. But any remarks, fixes and advice are more than welcome.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is apure PHP problem, why did you tag the question with Javascript, JSON, and AJAX?

Comment: @NicoHaase do apologize for the inconvenience caused, the matter relating to tags is rectified now.

Comment: As said... You are practically deleting the $output['data'] by assigning it to array. Open Web developer tools in your browser (commonly ctrl+shift+i or find out on Google how to do so) and navigate to "network tab" click on the last (the wanted) request and you can debug it... You wan to navigate deeper to response tab (and other tabs as well... headers + request tabs)

Comment: @digitalniweb I have used breakpoints on the insert function and XHR/fetch breakpoints, but it gives me nothing. And as mentioned above and by you that I’m the `$output['data']` by assigning it to the array, and as result, I get the **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**, an error which prevents the further code for correct executing. The row itself has been added to the database. I’m trying to find out how to assign the `$output['data']` to the last added row, which is defined in the INSERT statement.

Comment: @digitalniweb Here is what have tried to add to PHP file : `$last_id = $conn->insert_id; $queryTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT id , name FROM location WHERE id= ?'); $queryTest->bind_param("isi", $_REQUEST[$last_id], $_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST[$last_id] ); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $output['data'] = $row;` . But it didn't work.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. That should also include some more details about what **exactly** is not working

Comment: @Raimonds Ozolins We need you to show us what you get in the response on your front-end as I described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// remove next two lines for production

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

// this includes the login details

include("config.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$conn = new mysqli($cd_host, $cd_user, $cd_password, $cd_dbname, $cd_port, $cd_socket);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    
    $output['status']['code'] = "300";
    $output['status']['name'] = "failure";
    $output['status']['description'] = "database unavailable";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = [];

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($output);

    exit;

}   


$query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO location(name) VALUES(?)');

$query->bind_param("s", $_REQUEST['name']); 

$query->execute();

$lastId = $conn -> insert_id;

if (false === $query) {

    $output['status']['code'] = "400";
    $output['status']['name'] = "executed";
    $output['status']['description'] = "query failed";  
    $output['data'] = [];

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($output); 

    exit;

}

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM location WHERE id =  ?');

$query->bind_param("i", $lastId);

$query->execute();

if (false === $query) {

    $output['status']['code'] = "400";
    $output['status']['name'] = "executed";
    $output['status']['description'] = "query failed";  
    $output['data'] = [];

    echo json_encode($output); 

    mysqli_close($conn);
    
    exit;

}

$result = $query->get_result();

$data = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    array_push($data, $row);

}

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
$output['data'] = $data;

echo json_encode($output); 

mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to yuor answer such that others can learn from it